# How to Pinia Test => Method calling another => toHaveBeenCalledTimes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia, vitest

I'm fairly new to Vue 3 and Pinia,
but I could not find an answer to my Question so far...
So lets dive into my problem...

I have following Example Store:

```
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

const useExamplePiniaStore = defineStore('example-pinia-store', () => {
  const count = ref(0)
  
  function increment() {
    count.value += 1
  }
  
  function increaseBy10() {
    count.value += 10
  }

  function increaseBy11() {
    increment()
    increaseBy10()
  }
  
  return {
    count,
    increment,
    increaseBy10,
    increaseBy11
  }
})
```

And following Test File:

```
import { describe, it, expect, beforeEach, vi } from 'vitest'
import { setActivePinia } from 'pinia'
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'
import usePiniaStoreExample from '@/examples/ExamplePiniaStore'

describe('ExamplePiniaStore.ts', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(createTestingPinia({ createSpy: vi.fn, stubActions: false }))
  })

  it('test increase', () => {
    const store = usePiniaStoreExample()

    expect(store.count).toBe(0)
    expect(store.increaseBy10).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)

    store.increaseBy10()
    expect(store.count).toBe(10)
    expect(store.increaseBy10).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    store.increaseBy11()
    expect(store.count).toBe(21)
    expect(store.increaseBy10).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
  })
})
```

**My Problem:**
I would like to test that "increaseBy10" has been called by "increaseBy11" without changeging its implementation.

The Check `expect(store.count).toBe(21)` shows that the value has changed accordingly,
but `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)` always says "AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called 2 times, but got 1 times." and I do not understand why and what I'm doing wrong.

I have tried to find other / similar Problems, but I was either to stupid to understand the Issue or the Solution was for Jest or other Testing Frameworks and I was not able to make the solutions work for me.

Any help and explaination is highly appriciated.
Thank you.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of Pinia setup function instead of setup options limits the testability. `increaseBy11` refers local `increaseBy10` function, there's no way how it could be spied or mocked outside setup function scope.

This won't happen if actions are consistently referred as `this` methods:

```
actions: 
  increaseBy10() {
    this.count += 10
  },
  increaseBy11() {
    this.increment()
    this.increaseBy10()
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I verified and it works with an "Option Store".